# How to get the first element value of a php object

Tags: php, class, object, pdo

I am running pdo queries on different database tables and i am getting the following object result

```
object(stdClass)#6 (8) { 
    ["user_id"]=> string(2) "36" 
    ["username"]=> string(10) "nomoinc123"
    ....
}
```

If i wanted to get the user_id i would have to write

```
$obj->user_id
```

However, i want to get user_id without having to explicitly write it so that when i do queries on other tables it would get that first Primary Key entry regardless of its name

NB: All my Primary keys are written in this format name_id

Comment: I think you should check out ORM concept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can guarantee it is the first value you need (as the title of your question suggests), then `reset` will do what you want:

```
$firstvalue = reset($obj);
```

But it would make more sense if you would change your SQL query to return the key with a fixed alias. For example:

```
select user_id as key,
       /* some other fields come here */
from   users
```

And then you would just do `$obj->key`.

Comment: Thank you very much the reset() worked. As for the alias method, i am using PDO prepared statements that also do not allow me to explicitly write the column name